# Redis-stack docker customize

Tags: redis, redis-stack

I want to customize the redis-stack using Dockerfile by adding config file but not work yet

```
FROM redis/redis-stack:latest

ENV PORT=6379
ENV RIPORT=8001

WORKDIR /db
COPY redis.conf ./redis-stack.conf

EXPOSE 6379 8001

CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis-stack.conf" ]
```

I can not access to redis insight port

Comment: Is there a reason you are not referencing the file you copied `redis-stack.conf`? Otherwise it works on my configuration. What does not work exactly, do you see logs in the container or can't you connect to it?

Comment: My mistake, I updated the Dockerfile info. The issue is unable to connect the Redis Insight (I used K8s and mapping `8001` with a specific port)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use the redis-stack image to run both Redis Stack server and RedisInsight, but you are not exposing the correct port for RedisInsight. The default port for RedisInsight is 8001, but you are exposing 8001 as the port for Redis Stack server. This may cause a conflict or a connection error when you try to access RedisInsight.

To fix this, you need to change the port mapping in your Dockerfile, so that Redis Stack server uses 6379 and RedisInsight uses 8001. For example, you can do something like this:

```
FROM redis/redis-stack:latest

ENV PORT=6379
ENV RIPORT=8001

WORKDIR /db
COPY redis.conf ./redis-stack.conf

EXPOSE 6379 8001

CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis-stack.conf", "--port", "$PORT", "--riport", "$RIPORT" ]
```

Actually change:

```
CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis-stack.conf" ]
```

To:

```
CMD [ "redis-stack-server", "redis-stack.conf", "--port", "$PORT", "--riport", "$RIPORT" ]
```

This way, you can access Redis Stack server on localhost:6379 and RedisInsight on localhost:8001.